# Evaluation of the NOT operator

Tags: logic, associativity

Suppose that we have three logical variables $X,Y$, and $Z$ such that

$$X=TRUE$$
$$Y=FALSE$$
$$Y=TRUE$$

Let the $NOT$ operator be represented as

$$.NOT.$$

and the $AND$ operator be represented as

$$.AND.$$

What would happen if we performed the $NOT$ operator on these three variables in the following manner

$$(X.NOT.Y).NOT.Z=X.NOT.(Y.NOT.Z)$$

According to [this website](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/logical.html), the operation would be associative from right to left. So, I think that this would evaluate as

$$!(X.AND.Y).NOT.Z=X.NOT.!(Y.AND.Z)$$

or

$$!(!(X.AND.Y).AND.Z)=!(!(Y.AND.Z).AND.X)$$

Therefore, with the $X,Y,Z$ as defined above,

$$!(TRUE.AND.Z)=!(TRUE.AND.X)$$

or

$$FALSE=FALSE$$

Is this the correct analysis of the $NOT$ operator (change $X.NOT.Y$ to $!(X.AND.Y))$?

Comment: $.NOT.$ is not a binary operator. what does $X.NOT.Y$ mean?

Comment: I interpreted $X.NOT.Y$ as $!(X.AND.Y)$.

Comment: That is not NOT; it is [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate). NAND is not associative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account your funny notation (which by the way you should have mentioned in your post), let X = TRUE, Y = TRUE, Z = FALSE:
$$(X.NAND.Y).NAND.Z = FALSE.NAND.Z = TRUE \\\ne FALSE = X.NAND.TRUE = X.NAND.(Y.NAND.Z)$$

Also in the website you have linked to, $.NOT.$ is a unary operator, as it should be.

Comment: I see, I shouldn't have attempted to analyze the $NOT$ operator as a binary operator. The properties of associativity and commulativity don't apply to $NOT$ as it is a unary operator and not a binary operator.